# Не работает тег background-image в файле CSS

Tags: html, css

решил попробовать изучить язык HTML и столкнулся с такой проблемой:
В файле CSS не работает тег background-image, т.е. в корневом(не знаю, правильно ли я его назвал, если нет, поправьте, пожалуйста) файле index.html он работает, а именно из css - нет, я все уже перепробовал, сам CSS работает, два блока выставлены так, как я выставил, а вот именно этот тег нет.

Вот весь код из корня:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stil.css">
      <title>Document</title>
    </head>
  <body>
      <div class="bar">Главная</div>
      <div class="telo">Главная</div>

  </body>
</HTML>
```

А вот CSS:

```
.body{
    background-image: url(../img/fon.png);
    background-size: cover;
}

.telo{
    width: 950px;
    height: 1000px;
    left: 180px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px;
    border: solid 1px black;
    float: left;
    top: 70px;
}

.bar{
    background: black;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 30px;
    left: 150px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
    top: 40px;  
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема? Что я не так делаю? Права стоят максимальные, перед путем стоит двоеточие(и без него и как только я не пробовал) и выставлял CLASS тегу, и ставил ID и вообще все перепробовал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
body{
    background-image: url('data:image/jpeg;base64,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');
    background-size: cover;
}

.telo{
    width: 950px;
    height: 1000px;
    left: 180px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px;
    border: solid 1px black;
    float: left;
    top: 70px;
}

.bar{
    background: black;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 30px;
    left: 150px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
    top: 40px;  
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, это заработало, току убрал, запомнил. А как быть именно с блоком? Я хочу задать блоку telo такой же тег, что бы оно имело фон, как в таком случае делать?

Comment: Но ведь уже есть обращение к данному блоку, и там выставлены его параметры, но если дописать к этим параметрам данный тэг, он так же не работает. Как в таком случае быть?

Comment: Да, все получилось, спасибо вам огромное) Вы бог) Я тут парил голову двое суток, а дело было в одной точке -_-